# apt-get purge does not uninstall completely

Tags: debian, apt

I have installed emacs with `apt-get`. I tried to remove it later on, but the binary is left.

```
root@ionian:/home/gauthier# apt-get --purge remove emacs
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'emacs' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
root@ionian:/home/gauthier# which emacs
/usr/bin/emacs
root@ionian:/home/gauthier#
```

(the purge shown above is not the first attempt, this is just to show that the package was already removed.)

emacs was not installed before I did `apt-get install emacs`.

Any idea what is going on? Why doesn't apt-get see the binary, why does it think emacs is already uninstalled? What would have been a clean way to uninstall emacs completely?

Comment: What happens if you run `dpkg -S /usr/bin/emacs`?

Comment: Packages own files but files do not belong to packages. A system usually determines whether or not a package is installed by looking at a database, not by looking for the files the package would own.

Comment: `dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /usr/bin/emacs`

Comment: @EvanTeitelman: ok, but then why didn't my first attempt of purge clean the binary? Unfortunately I don't have the result of the (most) successful purge anymore.

Comment: ...and `file $(which emacs)`?

Comment: @JosephR.: /usr/bin/emacs: symbolic link to `/etc/alternatives/emacs'

Comment: Well it seems that `/usr/bin/emacs` is just a symlink that was put in place by the `emacs` package but isn't removed by the package's uninstall scripts. What do you get with `file /etc/alternatives/emacs` and `dpkg -S /etc/alternatives/emacs`?

Comment: It turns out that a couple of packages were still installed, which I noticed thanks to synaptic (emacs23-lucid, e.g.). Removing them there solved the problem. But these were installed when I installed emacs with `apt-get`, so they should also be removed by the `purge`, shouldn't they?

Comment: No. Packages pulled in as dependencies for a package you explicitly installed are marked as "automatically installed" and aren't removed. The original purge should have told you that these packages were no longer necessary and can be removed via `apt-get autoremove` (think a 1000 times before issuing this command, however)

Comment: If your problem is solved, please consider answering your own question.

Comment: But I did autoremove! The practical problem is solved, but I still want to understand what happened, why the dependencies were not removed upon `purge` and `autoremove`.

Comment: Maybe some other package depended on `emacs23`? You can see that with `aptitude why emacs23`.

Comment: I don't think that if `which` returns a filename that necessarily means there is actually a file there. It just tells you what system the file will try to execute for that command. If you want to see if a file is actually there, you could just do `ls -la`.

Answer (score 5):

Removing "emacs" do not clean `/usr/bin/emacs` because the latter is not provided by "emacs" package.

On Debian there are different flavours of emacs so `/usr/bin/emacs` is a symlink to particular executable that is used by default. You can choose which application to use by running command:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config emacs
```

Also package "galternatives" provides nice GUI application to manage alternatives.

If you run `aptitude show emacs` you may see that "emacs" is a metapackage which merely depends on some other packages that provide emacs executable. When you purged "emacs" it was fully uninstalled but its dependency package(s) may be still present on your system. You can remove them with

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

or if you use `aptitude` it will automatically suggest to remove automatically installed packages.

To get rid of `/usr/bin/emacs` you will have to uninstall all emacs alternatives such as "emacs23" or "emacs24" or any "emacs-*" packages.

Run the following command to find which executables are available as emacs alternatives

```
update-alternatives --list emacs
```

Also you may find `dlocate` utility useful to find which package provides a particular file.

Read more about alternatives in

- [Debian FAQ](http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-faq/ch-customizing.en.html#s-diverse).
- [update-alternatives(8)](http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=update-alternatives&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=Debian+7.0+wheezy&format=html&locale=en)

Comment: Thanks for this. I remember that some kind of `lucid` flavour left, although I did run `autoremove`. This is what I don't understand, `autoremove` did not seem to remove all dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

You may still have `emacs23` and friends installed.

```
sudo apt-get remove emacs*
```