# How does `apt` check for dependency removal when uninstalling/purging ? AkA Help me understand the behavior of `apt`

Tags: apt, dependencies

I was fiddling with sound on linux and tried installing the package `jackd`. This is the relevant excerpt of what `apt` returned :

```
$ sudo apt install jackd
The following additional packages will be installed:
  jackd2 jackd2-firewire libconfig++9v5 libffado2 libglibmm-2.4-1v5 libsigc++-2.0-0v5 libxml++2.6-2v5 python-dbus python-gi qjackctl
```

Then the result of a purge :

```
$ sudo apt purge jackd
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  jackd* qjackctl*
```

A subsequent installation :

```
$ sudo apt install jackd
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  jackd
```

----------EDIT----------

And then :

```
sudo apt autoremove
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libfwup1
```

(which is a package that was already mentioned before ever installing jackd)

----------END OF EDIT----------

From this experiment, `apt` doesn't seem to remove dependencies. However, the purging did remove another package (`qjackctl`) in addition to the one that I specifically mentioned (`jackd`).

`qjackctl` is the package for the corresponding GUI interface of the daemon `jackd` and I understand that it won't be needed if I don't have `jackd` anymore. But, logically, so are the other dependencies installed, so :

- why weren't they uninstalled ?
- why was `qjackctl` uninstalled ?
- why was `qjackctl` not fetched in the second installation ?

Only [thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/84328/apt-get-purge-does-not-uninstall-completely) found was specific to the package in question.

Thanks a lot for your help

PS : I just finished installing an Arch Linux partition (which is aimed to replace my Ubuntu one in the future). I'm not very familiar with `pacman` right now. Is this behavior better managed with this package manager ? (more precisely : indempotent operations and predictable behavior)

Answer (score 1):

The additional packages were installed because they are (possibly indirect) dependencies of `jackd`: `jackd2` directly, the rest through `jackd2`. `qjackctl` was installed because `jackd2` recommends it, and recommended packages are installed by default.

In detail, the dependency tree of the installed packages is as follows:

```
jackd
└─ jackd2
   ├─ python-dbus
   │  └─ python-gi (recommended)
   ├─ jackd2-firewire (recommended)
   │  └─ libffado2
   │     ├─ libconfig++9v5
   │     ├─ libglibmm-2.4-1v5
   │     │  └─ libsigc++-2.0-0v5
   │     └─ libxml++2.6-2v5
   └─ qjackctl (recommended)
```

Two additional dependencies don’t influence the installation step but become significant later: `jackd2-firewire` depends on `jackd2`, and `qjackctl` depends on `jackd`.

The latter dependency means that when `jackd2` was removed, `qjackctl` had to be removed too (you can’t have a package installed without its strict dependencies). The other packages don’t depend on `jackd`, so they weren’t removed; they would have been by `apt autoremove`, except that because `jackd2-firewire` depends on `jackd2`, none of the packages become unnecessary... (`apt` doesn’t remember *which specific package* caused another package to be installed; `autoremove` only checks automatically installed packages to see whether nothing depends on them any more. As an added twist, `autoremove` considers recommendations as important enough to keep a package installed.)

The second time you installed `jackd`, `apt` looked at its dependencies, *i.e.* `jackd2` or `jackd1`, noticed that `jackd2` was already installed, and stopped there; it therefore didn’t notice that `qjackctl` was “missing”, since it’s recommended by `jackd2`, not `jackd` itself.

`aptitude` will remove unnecessary packages as soon as their depending packages are removed, with no separate `autoremove` step; you might find it easier to use. The commands are the same as `apt`’s; it also has a text-based full-screen user interface which I find very useful.

Comment: Very sorry I forgot about `autoremove`. But it acutally did not remove the other dependencies. I just put the output of a `sudo apt autoremove` in an edit of the post.

Comment: That’s `apt autoremove` *after* re-installing `jackd`, isn’t it? Then the packages are no longer candidates for auto-removal...

Comment: No it was actually after `sudo apt purge jackd`. But I understood the issue thanks to you. `jackd2` was still installed and with a `sudo apt remove jackd2`, all the other dependencies are effectively removed. But then the issue is `jackd2` being separated from `jackd` as a standalone package instead of being a dependency of `jackd2`.

Comment: knowing the info I provided, shouldn't `jackd2` (and its dependencies) be removed by an `autoremove` ? I made sure to remove every sing package that was installed in the first place, to return in a clean state for a `sudo apt install jackd`. All the other packages were effectively added. And I can reproduce the same behavior, which is that `jackd2` is not fetched by `autoremove`.

Comment: Right, see the update; `jackd2-firewire` keeps `jackd2` installed.